# cannot pass + symbol to php page for processing

Tags: php, html, get, url-parameters

i have a dropdown as below,

```
<select name="pid" onchange="getReport(this.value)">
<option>Select a PID:</option>
<option value="SFP-GE-S">SFP-GE-S</option>
<option value="SFP-OC12-MM">SFP-OC12-MM</option>
<option value="SFP-OC3-MM">SFP-OC3-MM</option>
<option value="XENPAK-10GB-LR+">XENPAK-10GB-LR+</option>
<option value="XENPAK-10GB-SR">XENPAK-10GB-SR</option>
</select>
```

m passing the selected value to my send.php via ajax call via GET ie im calling send.php?pid=value . But wen i select "XENPAK-10GB-LR+" option its only passing on as "XENPAK-10GB-LR " and the + symbol is not there due to which my DB query is going wrong. Can someone help over come this problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` in a URL is a special character representing a space. You need to [URL encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) the value before you concatenate it into a URL.

Answer (score 3):

when you pass the parameter use `escape` function in the javascript to url encode.

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter needs to be urlencoded, + is a space symbol in a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to encode URL

```
var myURL = encodeURIComponent(yourURL);
```